# Create folder in document library using SharePoint workflow

Tags: c#, visual-studio, sharepoint-2007, workflow, sharepoint-designer

I want to create folder inside my document library based on other document library in the root. And I want to run this workflow on new document library creation.

So let say I have 4 document library:

- Help
- News
- Doc
- Archive

I want to create folder inside "Archive" Document library when New document library is created.

- Help
- News
- Doc
- Archive
- New Doc Library

and in Archive document library it will create folders

- Help
- News
- Doc
- New Doc Library

Is it possible..?

How can I do it.??

--

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

```
string archiveListUrl = "http://myserver/Archive/";
SPSite site;
SPWeb web;
SPDocumentLibrary library;

using (site = new SPSite(archiveListUrl))
using (web = site.OpenWeb())
{
   library = (SPDocumentLibrary)web.Lists["Archive"];
   web.Folders.Add(archiveListUrl + "Help");
   web.Folders.Add(archiveListUrl + "News");
   web.Folders.Add(archiveListUrl + "Doc");
   web.Folders.Add(archiveListUrl + "New Doc Library");
   library.Update();
}
```

Comment: Hi Steve, Thanks for Reply. But, Here I dont have only 4 document library. I want this workflow to run when New Document Library is created. How can I get new document library name and run workflow when new document library is created.??

Thanks again.

Answer (score 0):

Thats difficult: Workflows are are always attached to one document/item. One thing you could do: Create the Library from a customized template - and you can customize this lib with an workflow to start on creation of a doc. Then add a document to the library and save the whole thing as template with content.

(Actually you might check if creating a lib template with existing folders might be easier...)